# Flutter Google Cloud Functions Get UID of Firestore trigger

Tags: javascript, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

i want to use Google Cloud Functions to count documents in firestore and show a counter in the app.

So I have the following code which is working:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const {FieldValue} = require("@google-cloud/firestore/build/src");

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().functions);
const doc = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc('CF7FOjfZ0iOlwXBc59AAEM7Qx1').collection('user').doc('general');


exports.countDocs = functions.firestore
    .document('/users/CF7FOjfZ0iOlwXBc59AAEM7Qx1/trainings/{trainings}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {


        if (!change.before.exists) {
            // New document Created : add one to count
            doc.update({numberOfDocs: FieldValue.increment(1)});
        } else if (change.before.exists && change.after.exists) {
            // Updating existing document : Do nothing
        } else if (!change.after.exists) {
            // Deleting document : subtract one from count
            doc.update({numberOfDocs: FieldValue.increment(-1)});
        }
    });
```

Now I have the problem, that I need to get the uid of current user. I don't know how to do that. For Realtime firebase there is a possible solution with context, but Google has not implemented this for Firestore.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your question is. You seem to already know that the UID of the current user is not automatically available on Cloud Functions that are triggered by Firestore, and that you need to pass the UID in the path that triggers the function. What is your question for us?

Comment: Thanks for ur response. The question is how do I get the UID of the current user. I need it because of my firestore structure /users/uid. Otherwise I can't use cloud functions

Comment: Is `CF7FOjfZ0iOlwXBc59AAEM7Qx1` static or will it become a wildcard such as userId?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep a count for each user, that'd be:

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().functions);

exports.countDocs = functions.firestore
.document('/users/{uid}/trainings/{trainings}')
// Capture uid here 
.onWrite((change, context) => {
    const doc = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(context.params.uid).collection('user').doc('general');
                            // User uid here 

    if (!change.before.exists) {
        // New document Created : add one to count
        doc.update({numberOfDocs: FieldValue.increment(1)});
    } else if (change.before.exists && change.after.exists) {
        // Updating existing document : Do nothing
    } else if (!change.after.exists) {
        // Deleting document : subtract one from count
        doc.update({numberOfDocs: FieldValue.increment(-1)});
    }
});
```